# MobileFirst HTTPS android application

Tags: android, https, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to build a hybrid MobileFirst 6.3 application for android with an HTTPS endpoint. When I change the endpoint from http://domain.com.ar to https://domain.com.ar, my application crashes at launch even if i add the 443 port.

```
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369): Process: com.NevadaApp, PID: 21369
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.NevadaApp/com.NevadaApp.NevadaApp}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Port is invalid: -1
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Port is invalid: -1
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Scheme.java:100)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at com.worklight.wlclient.HttpClientManager.<init>(HttpClientManager.java:82)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at com.worklight.wlclient.HttpClientManager.createInstance(HttpClientManager.java:214)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLClient.createInstance(WLClient.java:214)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at com.worklight.common.Logger.setContext(Logger.java:513)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at com.worklight.androidgap.api.WL.<init>(WL.java:57)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at com.worklight.androidgap.api.WL.createInstance(WL.java:87)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at com.NevadaApp.NevadaApp.onCreate(NevadaApp.java:20)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
04-20 12:06:00.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21369):    ... 11 more
```

**wlclient.properties**

```
wlServerProtocol = https
wlServerHost = mydomain.com.ar
wlServerPort = 443
wlServerContext = /mycontext/
wlAppId = myapp
wlAppVersion = 1.0
GcmSenderId = 15237827348
enableSettings = false
testWebResourcesChecksum = false
ignoredFileExtensions =
webResourcesSize = 3450084
wlUid = YEMpiq8YJpispN592p046A==
wlPlatformVersion = 6.3.0.0 
wlMainFilePath = index.html
wlShareCookies =
wlShareUserCert = false
wlSecureDirectUpdatePublicKey =
```

Any help?

Comment: What is the complete MobileFirst version number? You can find it by going to 'About Eclipse' and clicking on the MobileFrist logo. If you are on an old version you will have to upgrade.

Comment: In addition to Chevy's question, also mention what is the end point you're changing, adapter? app? where are you changing it?

Comment: the version is 6.3.0.00-20141218-1823 , its a developers edition from the market place, also the only change that i did was in the chage in the build setting and deploy target  i´ve changed the http for https

Comment: Can you post the contents `wlclient.properties` file?

Comment: wlServerProtocol = https
wlServerHost = mydomain.com.ar
wlServerPort = 443
wlServerContext = /mycontext/
wlAppId = myapp
wlAppVersion = 1.0
GcmSenderId = 15237827348
enableSettings = false
testWebResourcesChecksum = false
ignoredFileExtensions = 
webResourcesSize = 3450084
wlUid = YEMpiq8YJpispN592p046A==
wlPlatformVersion = 6.3.0.0
wlMainFilePath = index.html
wlShareCookies = 
wlShareUserCert = false
wlSecureDirectUpdatePublicKey =

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the latest build. This was an APAR that was already addressed.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI31560

Comment: thanks a lot, ive install the 6.3.0.0-MFPF-StudioP2-IF201504041503 patch, and that solve my problem